# Logarithmic regression with three constants (or coefficients)?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

Looking for a method, model, or program that can assist with logarithmic regression of the (apparently unusual) form: y = a + b*log(x - c). In other words, assuming a data subset from the middle of a larger data set of which the initial x value is unknown - only the relative position of the values in the subset are known, relative to each other that is. Apologies for poor phrasing if that is unclear. Further apologies if there is something obvious I am missing, been trying to figure this out for the last couple hours (and several months off and on before that, lol).